# Mac Spyder ipython console stuck on connecting to kernel

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, ipython, spyder

I have downloaded Spyder on Mac OS today, however to work with other modules i installed earlier, I switched the Python executable to `usr/local/bin` in Spyder preference.

The python console correctly points to this location, however the iPython console kept showing "connecting to kernel". I have checked in Terminal that:

```
$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
$ which ipython
/usr/local/bin/ipython
```

So I guess spyder is indeed pointing to the right executable?
One hint however, is that

```
$ python
---- opens python 2.7.11
$ ipython
---- opens python 2.7.10
```

When I open by "python"

```
>>> import IPython
>>> IPython
<module 'IPython' from '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/__init__.pyc'>
>>>
```

So it looks that the two refer to different python? I am really confused by the settings here, could anyone please help?
Thanks a lot!